# gnu parellel re-run when it fails with a while loop

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, append, gnu-parallel

Assuming we have a csv file

```
1
2
3
4
```

Here is the code:

```
cat A.csv | while read A; do

echo "echo $A" > $A.sh

echo "$A.sh"

done | xargs -I {} parallel --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: {}
```

The above is a simplified case.  But pretty much get the bulk part.  The parallel here will run like this:

```
parallel --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh 4.sh
```

Now assume 3.sh failed for some reasons. Is there going to be any easy way to rerun the failed 3.sh in the current shell script setting within the same line of parallel command? I have tried the following, but it doesnt works and quite lengthy.

```
cat A.csv | while read A; do

echo "echo $A" > $A.sh

echo "$A.sh"

done | xargs -I {} parallel --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: {}

# The above will do this:

# parallel --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh 4.sh

cat A.csv | while read A; do

echo "echo $A" > $A.sh

echo "$A.sh"

done | xargs -I {} parallel --resume-failed --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: {}  

# The above will do this:

# parallel --resume-failed --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh 4.sh
```

######## 2017-09-25

Thanks Ole. I have tried the following

```
doit() {
   myarg="$1"

if [ $myarg -eq 3 ]

then
        exit 1

else

echo do crazy stuff with "$myarg"

fi

}
export -f doit



parallel -k --retries 3 --joblog ole.log doit :::: A.csv
```

It returns the log file like this:

```
Seq     Host    Starttime       JobRuntime      Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1       :       1506362303.003       0.016      0       22      0       0       doit 1
2       :       1506362303.006       0.013      0       22      0       0       doit 2
3       :       1506362303.026       0.002      0       0       1       0       doit 3
4       :       1506362303.014       0.006      0       22      0       0       doit 4
```

However, I dont see the doit 3 being retried 3 times as expected.  Could you enlighten?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Generating .sh files seems like a bad idea. You can most likely just make a function instead:

```
doit() {
   myarg="$1"
   echo do crazy stuff with "$myarg"
}
export -f doit
```

To retry a failing command use `--retries`:

```
parallel --retries 3 doit :::: file.csv
```

If your CSV-file has multiple columns, use `--colsep`:

```
parallel --retries 3 --colsep '\t' doit :::: file.csv
```

Using this:

```
doit() {
   myarg="$1"

  if [ $myarg -eq 3 ] ; then
      echo do not do crazy stuff with "$myarg"
      exit 1
  else
      echo do crazy stuff with "$myarg"
  fi
}
export -f doit
```

This will retry '3' job 3 times:

```
parallel -k --retries 3 --joblog ole.log doit ::: 1 2 3 4
```

It will only log the last time. To be convinced this actually runs thrice, run the output unbuffered:

```
parallel -u --retries 3 --joblog ole.log doit ::: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks @Ole Tange.  I have tried and made an edit in the original post. The retries doesn't seem to work as expected.  Could you enlighten?  Thanks.